# Access Geolocation on webview react-native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

// ...
class MyWebComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} />;
  }
}
```

i want to connect my webview to a website that needs geolocation .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `geolocationEnabled`. Set whether Geolocation is enabled in the WebView. The default value is false. Used only in Android.

Also, you need to configure geolocation permissions in your app.

`android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```